# How to draw a circle filled with four colors?

Tags: iphone

Anybody? I want to draw a circle in core graphics with four colors in it. i.e. four equally distributed colors, one in each quarter of the circle.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect mainSquare = self.bounds;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Create circle path and clip

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, mainSquare);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // Define rects

    CGRect topLeft = CGRectMake(mainSquare.origin.x, mainSquare.origin.y, mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.size.height / 2);
    CGRect topRight = CGRectMake(mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.origin.y, mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.size.height / 2);
    CGRect bottomLeft = CGRectMake(mainSquare.origin.x, mainSquare.size.height / 2, mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.size.height / 2);
    CGRect bottomRight = CGRectMake(mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.size.height / 2, mainSquare.size.width / 2, mainSquare.size.height / 2);

    // Define colors
    CGColorRef topLeftColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    CGColorRef topRightColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    CGColorRef bottomLeftColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    CGColorRef bottomRightColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];

    // Fill rects with colors
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, topLeftColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, topLeft);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, topRightColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, topRight);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, bottomLeftColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bottomLeft);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, bottomRightColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bottomRight);


    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

Comment: 0
1
 

How to rotate a circle(Fortune wheel) clockwise and anticlockwise by touching circle in particular direction.i.e. if I touch circle and drag my fingur on Iphone in clockwise direction 'my circle will start rotation in clockwise direction and vice versa. If anybody have an idea about it please share it as soon as possible. Thanx in advance